# File Storage Abstraction module for Node.js?

Tags: node.js, file-io, cloud-storage

Working on applications in PHP, I like to use a file storage abstraction layer (for instance [Flysystem](http://flysystem.thephpleague.com/)). This makes it trivial to switch between locations where files should be persisted to (cloud storage, local drive, ZIP, *whatever*).

Currently I am getting started in Node.js so I was wondering if a similar module exists for node?

Searching the NPM site gave me a **ton** of hits related to the filesystem but nothing in regards to this level of abstraction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of 2023 there is **[Flystorage](https://flystorage.dev/)**.

| FlyStorage | Has adapters for: |
| --- | --- |
| [image: FlyStorage Logo] <sup>Built by the maintainer of PHP FlySystem</sup> | Amazon S3 Azure Storage Blob Google Cloud Storage In-Memory Local filesystem (S)FTP Soon<sup>™️</sup> |

*For Node.js, written in TypeScript.*

Answer (score 7):

[pkgcloud](https://github.com/pkgcloud/pkgcloud#storage) integrates multiple services (compute, storage, database. etc) and supports multiple cloud providers. The storage service's API is simple to use and supports streams, making it memory efficient as well.

*Unfortunately, the project is longer maintained.*

Comment: Does this also support local file system?  Would be nice to abstract local from AWS.

Comment: It does not. However, I have made [cloudcp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloudcp) which uses pkgcloud under the hood and supports copying local files to the cloud.

Comment: Yes, it supports local file system through package `filesystem-storage-pkgcloud`. Add and then enable it in your code `var pkgcloud = require('pkgcloud'); pkgcloud.providers.filesystem = {}; pkgcloud.providers.filesystem.storage = require('filesystem-storage-pkgcloud');`.

Comment: FYI pkgcloud only abstracts those providers that the web service owner typically pays for and fully controls (e.g. AWS S3).  It does not support any storage providers that your users are responsible for (e.g. Google Drive.)

Answer (score 6):

There used to be [Flydrive](https://github.com/Slynova-Org/node-flydrive), but as of 2022 it is no longer maintained.

It has support for:

- Local
- Amazon S3
- Digital Ocean Spaces
- FTP

Comment: Unfortunately, the project is longer maintained as a stand-alone package. It has been integrated in the AdonisJS Framework.

Answer (score 5):

There is [`filefog`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/filefog), which is intended to support Google Drive, Dropbox, SkyDrive and Box, as well as the local filesystem. Like [`passport`](http://passportjs.org/) it uses ‘strategies’ published as separate modules for each provider (`filefog-dropbox`, `filefog-onedrive`, etc.).

However, it has not seen any activity since 2018.

Comment: Looks exactly like what I mean. I like the fact it uses the "promise" design pattern. Thanks!

Comment: I am _very_ curious why this answer gets downvoted without the downvoters stating what their problem with this answer is...